# nodejs error on logging to console

Tags: node.js, jenkins, stubbydb

I have created a plugin [stubbydb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stubby-db) that is running fine on local machine. But while running on a remote server using jenkins, I am getting following error.

```
2016-03-16T10:58:10.745Z - error: uncaughtException: write EPIPE date=Wed Mar 16 2016 10:58:10 GMT+0000 (GMT), pid=23729, uid=501, gid=500, cwd=/home/deployment, execPath=/usr/local/node/node-v5.2.0/bin/node, version=v5.2.0, argv=[/usr/local/node/node-v5.2.0/bin/node, /usr/local/node/node-default/bin/stubbydb, -d, /tmp/soa-simulator, -p, 7777, -s, /tmp/soa-simulator/], rss=22597632, heapTotal=12671264, heapUsed=8094384, loadavg=[1.7158203125, 0.68505859375, 0.27392578125], uptime=5615485, trace=[column=11, file=util.js, function=Object.exports._errnoException, line=856, method=exports._errnoException, native=false, column=20, file=util.js, function=exports._exceptionWithHostPort, line=879, method=_exceptionWithHostPort, native=false, column=14, file=net.js, function=WriteWrap.afterWrite, line=764, method=afterWrite, native=false], stack=[Error: write EPIPE,     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:856:11),     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:879:20),     at WriteWrap.afterWrite (net.js:764:14)]

2016-03-16T10:58:36.696Z - error: uncaughtException: This socket is closed. date=Wed Mar 16 2016 10:58:36 GMT+0000 (GMT), pid=23729, uid=501, gid=500, cwd=/home/deployment, execPath=/usr/local/node/node-v5.2.0/bin/node, version=v5.2.0, argv=[/usr/local/node/node-v5.2.0/bin/node, /usr/local/node/node-default/bin/stubbydb, -d, /tmp/soa-simulator, -p, 7777, -s, /tmp/soa-simulator/], rss=25243648, heapTotal=12671264, heapUsed=8775480, loadavg=[1.443359375, 0.7080078125, 0.291015625], uptime=5615511, trace=[column=19, file=net.js, function=Socket._writeGeneric, line=641, method=_writeGeneric, native=false, column=8, file=net.js, function=Socket._write, line=695, method=_write, native=false, column=12, file=_stream_writable.js, function=doWrite, line=293, method=null, native=false, column=5, file=_stream_writable.js, function=writeOrBuffer, line=279, method=null, native=false, column=11, file=_stream_writable.js, function=Socket.Writable.write, line=208, method=Writable.write, native=false, column=40, file=net.js, function=Socket.write, line=619, method=write, native=false, column=16, file=console.js, function=Console.log, line=37, method=log, native=false, column=12, file=/usr/local/node/node-v5.2.0/lib/node_modules/stubby-db/js/stubbyDB.js, function=, line=29, method=null, native=false, column=13, file=events.js, function=emitNone, line=68, method=null, native=false, column=7, file=events.js, function=IncomingMessage.emit, line=167, method=emit, native=false], stack=[Error: This socket is closed.,     at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:641:19),     at Socket._write (net.js:695:8),     at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:293:12),     at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:279:5),     at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:208:11),     at Socket.write (net.js:619:40),     at Console.log (console.js:37:16),     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/node/node-v5.2.0/lib/node_modules/stubby-db/js/stubbyDB.js:29:12),     at emitNone (events.js:68:13),     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:167:7)]
```

So till the time jenkins job is running stubbydb responses. But as soon as jenkins job is completed. It stopped working. And Gives error on `console.log()` statement.

If I login to the server and do `console.log("something")` on node console. I see no error. Moreover, if I run stubbydb directly there after login instead of jenkins. It works fine.

What can be the reason? Should I avoid writing to console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find anything wrong with the application. The problem is automatically solved. It seems to be with jenkins job or server setup. However I have removed all default console.log and made logging on demand. So if anyone face the same issue, just switch off the logging.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this ...

```
FunctionThrowingException().on("error", function(){
       //Handle exception here
});
```

on the function that is throwing the exception. I had this issue once, but with another application of Node. Handling the exception should do the job.

P.S. This is not the exact solution, as you have not provided the full code. So, just take this idea and go through your code. Should Help.

Comment: The fulle code is [here](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/StubbyDB/blob/master/js/stubbyDB.js)